# group by function issue when using sum statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I added a sum statement to a case when statement and its triggering a ORA-00937: not a single-group group function error.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT abc_value,
           COUNT (*) AS num_abc_values
    from   (
     select dsp_sku,
     sum(case
        when EXPTD_QTY <> ACTL_INVN_QTY then (EXPTD_QTY-ACTL_INVN_QTY)*(-1)
        else null
      end) as "Variance_"
    ,decode (cc.stat_code, '0', 'Unprocessed', '90', 'Processed', '99', 'Expired') as Status,
    trunc(cc.create_date_time) CC_date,
      case
        when dsp_sku = 'EGIA60AMT' then 'A'
        when dsp_sku = 'LF1937' then 'A'
        when dsp_sku = '980X3ENDIUU' then 'A'
        when dsp_sku = '186-0106' then 'A'
        when dsp_sku = 'PM35MN02' then 'A'
     when dsp_sku = 'SIGC60MT' then 'B'
        when dsp_sku = 'GS833' then 'B'
        when dsp_sku = '5.5 PED' then 'B'
        when dsp_sku = 'L74' then 'B'
        when dsp_sku = 'VLOCL2105' then 'B'
        when dsp_sku = 'VLOCM0134' then 'C'
        when dsp_sku = '8886471021V' then 'C'
        when dsp_sku = 'SILSCLINCH46' then 'C'
     when dsp_sku = 'YCN1800P' then 'D'
        when dsp_sku = 'YCN1801P' then 'D'
        when dsp_sku = 'Y-REFACH-X-E' then 'D'
        when dsp_sku = 'ZL7777-0091' then 'D'
        else 'Empty Location'
      end as ABC_Value
    from WH_GHC1.CYCLE_COUNT_HIST cc
      left join item_master im on
        im.sku_id = cc.sku_id
      inner join locn_hdr lh on
        lh.locn_id = cc.locn_id
    where
      cc.whse = 'PH3'
      --and cc.stat_code in ('0','90') --stat_code: 0 is unprocessed, 90 is processed, 99 is expired
      and cc.stat_code = 90
      --and cc.stat_code = 0
      --and cc.create_date_time between '&FromDate' and '&EndDate'

      and cc.create_date_time between '&FromDate' and '&ToDate'
    --and dsp_sku = '&SKU'
      --and not im.srl_nbr_reqd = 4
      --and EXPTD_QTY = 0
      --and actl_invn_qty = 0
      )
    GROUP BY ABC_Value, Dsp_sku
    --having count (Variance_) <>0;
```

ive tried re writing my group by, adding to the group by, getting rid of it and all with no luck...

I currently have it counting the values of ABC's... I want it to then sum the amount of variances there are for ABC's AS WELL. I believe the sum statement is right but triggering the ORA error... any suggestions...?

Comment: Your subquery has an aggregation function `sum(case when exptd_qty...)` but no `group by` clause.

Comment: I'm writing this as a comment cause i'm not entirely sure yet but i believe your group by should include your whole decode statement. And should be inside the subquery

Comment: the query works now but it creates a row for each variance. it does a row for each QTY and the amount of the variance, I would like it to just tell me how many there are. like 5 variance for a and 2 for b and so on. any advice...?

Answer (score 1):

I have adjusted and add comments to your script. May be this will not give you the desired output directly (more adjustment required from your part) but this will guide you towards your destination :)

```
SELECT 
abc_value, --No DISTINCT required 
COUNT (*) AS num_abc_values,
SUM(Variance_) AS Variance_
FROM  
(
    SELECT 

    --dsp_sku,
    --SUM
    --(
    CASE
        WHEN EXPTD_QTY <> ACTL_INVN_QTY THEN (EXPTD_QTY-ACTL_INVN_QTY)*(-1)
        ELSE NULL
    END AS 'Variance_',
    --decode (cc.stat_code, '0', 'Unprocessed', '90', 'Processed', '99', 'Expired') as Status,
    --trunc(cc.create_date_time) CC_date,

    -- All above columns:  dsp_sku, Variance_, Status, CC_date has no impace on the Final output
    --So you can exclude them from the selection

    CASE
        WHEN dsp_sku IN('EGIA60AMT','LF1937','980X3ENDIUU','186-0106','PM35MN02') THEN 'A'
        WHEN dsp_sku IN ('SIGC60MT','GS833','5.5 PED','L74','VLOCL2105') THEN 'B'
        WHEN dsp_sku IN ('VLOCM0134','8886471021V','SILSCLINCH46') THEN 'C'
        WHEN dsp_sku IN ('YCN1800P','YCN1801P','Y-REFACH-X-E','ZL7777-0091') then 'D'
        ELSE 'Empty Location'
    END AS ABC_Value
    -- You can use IN operator instead of checking all values one by one.

    FROM WH_GHC1.CYCLE_COUNT_HIST cc
    LEFT JOIN item_master im 
        ON im.sku_id = cc.sku_id
    INNER JOIN locn_hdr lh 
        ON lh.locn_id = cc.locn_id
    WHERE
    cc.whse = 'PH3'
    AND cc.stat_code = 90
    AND cc.create_date_time BETWEEN '&FromDate' AND '&ToDate'
)
GROUP BY ABC_Value
--, Dsp_sku  
-- This group by is unnecessary as ABC_Value already created from this column's value
```

Comment: I had the one case when statement     CASE
    --      WHEN EXPTD_QTY <> ACTL_INVN_QTY THEN (EXPTD_QTY-ACTL_INVN_QTY)*(-1)
    --      ELSE NULL
    --  END         calculating the varinces in qty that were counted, I want to have it sum together the amount there are to the letter a b c d... this will work for that?

Comment: Yes that should work without the SUM inside the Sub Query. You can then apply SUM on 'Variance_' if required in the final selection as - 

SELECT abc_value, COUNT (*) AS num_abc_values, SUM(Variance_)

Comment: its returning multiple lines for each letter and then the actual variance qty for the letter as well, can we make it only sum the amount of variances to the letter? like a has 5 variances and so on...                                                                                                                  C 21 21
C 1 -1044
A 14 -14
C 1 330
C 2 80
D 8 8
B 2 -40
C 1 -18
A 1 8
Empty Location 1 -67
C 1 972
C 1 -21
C 1 110

Comment: imagine all those number in a table format lol... they wouldn't paste right

Comment: I made some changes in the code. Check this works or not.

Comment: Still shows on all separate lines. then I could do the case when dsp_sku in because the max string is 1k line, Im using over 5k lines in some of it, that why I had originally made each line its own

Comment: Please add some sample data and your expected output. This will help.